# Program and Data are the Same in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have heard that in Prolog, program and data are the same thing. What does that mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that your program is implemented as a bunch of rules, and data is also implemented as a bunch of rules - there's no distinction between a rule that causes some operations to happen (a program), and a rule that just gives back a data value.

Answer (score 6):

Prolog source is just a list of rules. Some rules are just "data" - they are `true` without further evaluation.

```
person(james).
father(james, thomas).
```

"James is a person."
"James is the father of thomas."

These rules are the data.

I can run a query against this data. I can ask:

```
?- person(X).
```

The answer will be:

```
X = james.
```

Or:

```
?- father(X, thomas).
```

The answer will be the same.

Other rules need further evaluation.

```
grandfather(X, Z) :- father(X, Y), father(Y, Z).
```

This is a simple "program".

Our grandfather program will evaluate to true if we have the right data. For example:

```
father(james, william).
father(james, tyler).
father(james, thomas).
father(jeff, james).
```

If I execute the following program:

```
?- grandfather(jeff, X).
```

I get:

```
X = william
```

I can ask prolog to continue and I will get `X = tyler` and `X = thomas`.

The syntax gets more complicated, but the basics are the same. The data and the program are just a set of facts. The art of prolog is making the right rules that drive the computation to a result.

Answer (score 4):

This refers to terms being data, but the program also being described in terms.

Answer (score 4):

Just to put on my pedant's hat- the name for this is: homoiconic.  There's a lot of it about: machine Code is, also, homoiconic.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ?- A=write(B), C=(B is 1+2), Prog = (C, A).
A = write(B),
C = (B is 1+2),
Prog = (B is 1+2, write(B)).

 ?- $Prog.
3
true.
```